# Где ошибка в обьекте?

Tags: javascript

Нужно создать обьект вот такой структуры:

```
{"group":
{"first:[]},
{"second":[]}
}
```

Я создал, и у меня возле обьекта second редактор подсвечивает желтым цветом, значит где-то ошибка. Кроме того я проверил рабоет ли мое приложение - и нет, не работает, значит точно ошибка. Но я не могу понять где... Уже наверно раз 10 смотрю.
Вот скриншот:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Ну и сам обьект текстом:

```js
var a = {"group":
{"first":
[{"id":1,"firstName":"Alex","lastName":"Creel","email":"BGibson@placerat.ly","phone":"(898)979-8452"},
{"id":2,"firstName":"Todd","lastName":"Drek","email":"BGibson@placerat.ly","phone":"(898)979-8452"},
{"id":3,"firstName":"Jim","lastName":"Sparou","email":"BGibson@placerat.ly","phone":"(898)979-8452"},
{"id":4,"firstName":"Tom","lastName":"Limls","email":"BGibson@placerat.ly","phone":"(898)979-8452"},
{"id":5,"firstName":"Jack","lastName":"Retnd","email":"BGibson@placerat.ly","phone":"(898)979-8452"}]
},
{"second":
[{"id":6,"firstName":"Bill","lastName":"Milk","email":"BGibson@placerat.ly","phone":"(898)979-8452"},
{"id":7,"firstName":"Donald","lastName":"Nomk","email":"BGibson@placerat.ly","phone":"(898)979-8452"},
{"id":8,"firstName":"George","lastName":"Stoun","email":"BGibson@placerat.ly","phone":"(898)979-8452"},
{"id":9,"firstName":"Bredd","lastName":"kulr","email":"BGibson@placerat.ly","phone":"(898)979-8452"},
{"id":10,"firstName":"Djeck","lastName":"Topd","email":"BGibson@placerat.ly","phone":"(898)979-8452"}]
}
}
```

Comment: может для начала отформатируете нормально?

Comment: что отформатировать?

Comment: у меня кровь с глаз)
выложите сюда ваш объект полностью

Comment: конкретно такой структуры быть не может. `{"group":
{"first:[]},
{"second":[]}
}` в данном случае ошибка синтаксиса. Либо пропущены квадратные скобки, либо лишние фигурные

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const a = {
    "group": {
        "first": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "firstName": "Alex",
                "lastName": "Creel",
                "email": "BGibson@placerat.ly",
                "phone": "(898)979-8452"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "firstName": "Alex",
                "lastName": "Creel",
                "email": "BGibson@placerat.ly",
                "phone": "(898)979-8452"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "firstName": "Alex",
                "lastName": "Creel",
                "email": "BGibson@placerat.ly",
                "phone": "(898)979-8452"
            }
        ],
        "second": [
            {
                "id": 4,
                "firstName": "Bill",
                "lastName": "Milk",
                "email": "BGibson@placerat.ly",
                "phone": "(898)979-8452"
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "firstName": "Bill",
                "lastName": "Milk",
                "email": "BGibson@placerat.ly",
                "phone": "(898)979-8452"
            },
            {
                "id": 6,
                "firstName": "Bill",
                "lastName": "Milk",
                "email": "BGibson@placerat.ly",
                "phone": "(898)979-8452"
            }
        ]
    }
};


console.log(a.group);
```

У вас неправильно воссоздан объект, вам же выше подсказал Igor как сделать объект, вам просто нужно было вписать свои данные и все. **У вас объект не валиден**, **вам не может такое отдать сервер**.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var data = {
  "group": {
    "first":[],
    "second": []
  }
};
console.log(data);
```

Comment: я не понял вас...

Comment: @peterua Убрал лишние фигурные скобки.

Comment: мне нельзя что-то менять я делаю копию данных, которые получаю с API, просто удобнее будет так мне работать, ведь Api очень большое

Comment: @peterua В таком случае, данные - неправильные.

Comment: правильные) я ж не придумал) повторяюю структру один в один только где-то ошибку допустил а так как данние очень большие не могу сверить где ошибка

Comment: @peterua Я уже сказал Вам, где Вы допустили ошибку. Сравните Ваш и мой объекты.